# How to specify channel-specific package dependencies in conda package meta.yaml?

Tags: python, package, conda, conda-build

I've been following the tutorials here:

- https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html
- https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html

I can't figure out how to make package dependencies for my conda package.

Here's my `meta.yaml`:

```
{% set name = "fastq_preprocessor" %}
{% set version = "2022.01.19" %}

package:
  name: {{ name|lower }}
  version: {{ version }}
  script: python -m pip install --no-deps --ignore-installed .

source:
  url: https://github.com/jolespin/fastq_preprocessor/releases/download/v2022.01.19/fastq_preprocessor-2022.1.19.tar.gz

build:
  noarch: python
  number: 0

requirements:
  build:
    - python >=3.6
    - setuptools
  run:
    - python >=3.6

about:
  home: https://github.com/jolespin/fastq_preprocessor
  license: BSD-3
  license_family: BSD
  license_file: LICENSE.txt
  summary: 'A fastq preprocessor for short read sequencing'
  description: 'A fastq preprocessor for short read sequencing. Can be used as a wrapper around fastp for a standardized directory structure or can feed the trimmed reads into bowtie2 if an index is provided to decontaminate sequences similar to kneaddata (useful in metagenomics to remove host reads). Also includes functionality to filter based on k-mer profiles and is useful for quantifying the amount of ribosomal reads. At each stage, seqkit stats is run so there are read stats that can be used post hoc.'
```

For example, I want the installation to install: `fastp`, `bbmap`, etc. from `bioconda` package and `pandas` from `conda-forge`.

**How do I add these channel-specific dependencies into my `meta.yaml` so it installs them when the package is installed?**

I thought about doing a `conda env export` and then copy and pasting but I don't that's how it works.

Comment: You can't - it is not designed to work that way. The duplicate has a hacky workaround (I don't recommend it), but really it is up to the user to choose their channels, not the package.

Comment: Oh ok, I had no idea. So how do people create recipes where if I did something like `conda install -c bioconda samtools -y` it installs a bunch of other programs. How can I make my package do that? Is there a tutorial I overlooked?

Comment: I don't recall particular docs or a tutorial - just have seen this come up on GitHub and when building recipes. You still list the dependencies under `run:` (and `host:` if compiling), and then use `-c` flags with the `conda build` command to include the channels during the build. However, you need to note to the end users that they should use a particular channel order, like [what Bioconda has in their docs](http://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels). Basically, whatever channel order you use at build-time, they should use at installation time.